# Background color change from form field

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to create a form with the ability to let the user input a hex value, then upon click it applies that color.
I have it working in firefox unless there is a background image already chosen, and it won't work in IE at all(surprise surprise)
I think I need to have the background image removed first.
This is what I have so far

script

```
$("#newBodyColorBtn").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", $("#newBodyColor").val());
});
```

Form code

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="putcolor">
<strong>Put your color value here</strong> <input id="newBodyColor" type="text" value="" size="15">
<button id="newBodyColorBtn">Change Body Color</button>
</form>
```

i hope you guys can help

Cap;)

Comment: Have you tried just background instead of background-color?  That should null the image and all other background settings.

Comment: Thanks josh that sort out the bg image problem but the form will still not work in IE

Answer (score 0):

May help, color in hex without '#'

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeBG() {
   document.body.style.background = "#" + $("#newBodyColor").val();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Put your color value here #</strong> <input id="newBodyColor" type="text" value="" size="6">
<button id="newBodyColorBtn" onclick="changeBG()">Change Body Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thaks pilha i will look at this too

Answer (score 0):

```
// without jq:
//    document.getElementById("newBodyColorBtn").click(function(){

//with jq
$("#newBodyColorBtn").click(function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + document.getElementById("newBodyColor").value;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HnH5W/

works ;) (in Firefox), cant check IE with js fiddle... gets blocked